# AngularJs is responsive then why do we apply responsive layout? why isn’t it default?

Tags: angularjs

I read that angularjs is responsive framework then when we use angular material for web page then why web page by default is not responsive?

Answer (score 2):

AngularJS itself isn't responsive - it's purely a JavaScript framework. It's just commonly used for responsive websites.

Angular Material is a combined JavaScript/CSS framework which includes responsive CSS features (as many CSS frameworks do).